# Python разбор JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests

Имеется код:

```
{"stores":[{"id":"S319",
"name":"Пр-т им. Газеты «Красноярский Рабочий», д. 144",
"latitude":56.001,
"longitude":92.923,
"markerType":"mvideoStore",
"zoom":15,
"storeDetails":"/sitebuilder/blocks/browse/store/locator/storeDetails.json.jsp?storeId=S319&amp;hideBtn=true&amp;skuId="}]}
```

Как его разобрать модулем json?

Пытаюсь разобрать вот так:

```
json_data = json.loads(html)
json_text=json_data["stores"]
print(json_text)
```

Выдает ошибку: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'HtmlElement'`

Понимаю что нужно дойти до элемента, который содержит json, но структура страницы у меня отличается в Firefox и Chrome. Скорее всего это просто так браузеры отображают эти данные

Для парсинга использую lxml

Нужно вытащить latitude и longitude

Страница:[Ссылка на сайт](https://www.mvideo.ru/sitebuilder/blocks/browse/store/locator/store.json.jsp?storeId=S319&hideBtn=true&skuId=)

Comment: Интересно, а как вы переменную `html` получили? Можете в вопросе остальной код показать?

Comment: в html явно не текст. а видимо некий объект для работы с html. Посмотрите как получить содержимое этого объекта в виде текста, перед тем как отдавать его декодеру JSON

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Работает:

```
import json

text = """
{"stores":[{"id":"S319",
"name":"Пр-т им. Газеты «Красноярский Рабочий», д. 144",
"latitude":56.001,
"longitude":92.923,
"markerType":"mvideoStore",
"zoom":15,
"storeDetails":"/sitebuilder/blocks/browse/store/locator/storeDetails.json.jsp?storeId=S319&amp;hideBtn=true&amp;skuId="}]}
"""

data = json.loads(text)

store = data['stores'][0]
print(store['latitude'], store['longitude'])  # 56.001 92.923
```

Аналогичный результат будет если сделать запрос и обработать ответ (json):

```
import requests

rs = requests.get('https://www.mvideo.ru/sitebuilder/blocks/browse/store/locator/store.json.jsp?storeId=S319&hideBtn=true&skuId=')
data = rs.json()

store = data['stores'][0]
print(store['latitude'], store['longitude'])  # 56.001 92.923
```

Comment: спасибо, я просто превращал в дерево, вот и не получалось)

Answer (score 1):

Если указанный API вернет более одного элемента в списке с ключем `stores`, то удобно будет воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd
```

симулируем ответ API с двумя записями в `stores`:

```
In [60]: data = \
    ...: {'stores': [
    ...:   {'id': 'S319',
    ...:    'name': 'Пр-т им. Газеты Красноярский Рабочий, д. 144',
    ...:    'latitude': 56.001,
    ...:    'longitude': 92.923,
    ...:    'markerType': 'mvideoStore',
    ...:    'zoom': 15,
    ...:    'storeDetails': '/sitebuilder/blocks/browse/store/locator/storeDetails.json.jsp?storeId=S319&amp;hideBtn=true&amp;skuId='},
    ...:   {'id': 'S320',
    ...:    'name': 'Пр-т им. Газеты Красноярский Безработный, д. 411',
    ...:    'latitude': 56.001,
    ...:    'longitude': 92.923,
    ...:    'markerType': 'mvideoStore2',
    ...:    'zoom': 15,
    ...:    'storeDetails': '/sitebuilder/blocks/browse/store/locator/storeDetails.json.jsp?storeId=S319&amp;hideBtn=true&amp;skuId='},
    ...: ]}
```

преобразовываем словарь в DataFrame:

```
In [61]: df = pd.DataFrame(data['stores'])

In [62]: df
Out[62]:
     id  latitude  longitude    markerType                                              name  \
0  S319    56.001     92.923   mvideoStore      Пр-т им. Газеты Красноярский Рабочий, д. 144
1  S320    56.001     92.923  mvideoStore2  Пр-т им. Газеты Красноярский Безработный, д. 411

                                        storeDetails  zoom
0  /sitebuilder/blocks/browse/store/locator/store...    15
1  /sitebuilder/blocks/browse/store/locator/store...    15
```

чтобы получить строку с `id == 'S319'`:

```
In [63]: df.loc[df['id']=='S319']
Out[63]:
     id  latitude  longitude   markerType                                          name  \
0  S319    56.001     92.923  mvideoStore  Пр-т им. Газеты Красноярский Рабочий, д. 144

                                        storeDetails  zoom
0  /sitebuilder/blocks/browse/store/locator/store...    15
```

чтобы получить значения определенных столбцов для нужного `id` :

```
In [64]: df.loc[df['id']=='S319', ['latitude','longitude']]
Out[64]:
   latitude  longitude
0    56.001     92.923
```

в виде списка:

```
In [65]: df.loc[df['id']=='S319', ['latitude','longitude']].values.tolist()
Out[65]: [[56.001, 92.923]]
```

список всех значений столбца `name` в DataFrame:

```
In [66]: df['name'].values.tolist()
Out[66]:
['Пр-т им. Газеты Красноярский Рабочий, д. 144',
 'Пр-т им. Газеты Красноярский Безработный, д. 411']
```